# How do I make a Cube Background in Blender for Imvu?

Tags: mesh

This is my first time meshing ever, and I need some guidance on how to make objects without changing the avatar in IMVU. I want to make a room background, kind of like a wallpaper behind my avatar but in cube form. Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, most users here won't be familiar with the workflow from blender to IMVU (if one exists). What does the process entail? Do you make objects in blender and then export them in a specific format? Also, what do you mean "without changing the avatar"? Do you mean from a lighting/shading standpoint?

Comment: yes you make it in blender than export them in a specific format. I imported an imvu avatar into blender and I would like to know how to create a cube around it without affecting the avatar